# Young adult book (or movie?) about a solar flare?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This book (movie?) was about a group of students who were on a field trip that took them down deep underground. Something happened that made them have to go back up if I remember right, but once they get back to the surface it's not only hotter but anyone who is outside is dead and looks as if they have been boiled or burned.

They realize they can't go into the sunlight as it causes severe burns so they have to cover every part of their body to be able to travel. One of the kids parents is in the military or something so they try to go find them. I can't remember if they are a bad guy or not and I think part of the states were super cold maybe?

I found a book called [Flare](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25212682-flare) that is similar but doesn't have this story line.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13614942-land is five kids on a field trip when an EMP happens.

Comment: Did the book have a strong biblical /Christian theme to it?

Comment: It did not have a biblical or Christian theme that I remember

Comment: I'm guessing _Flare_ is the book by Jonathan Maas so I've added a link. If this is wrong please feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: When did you read or see it? Can you [edit] your question to include this info?